# Sending multiple functions through module.exports throw error

Tags: javascript, express

I have a file by the name utils. It mainly has two functions, isEmpty and isNumber. I am exporting both methids using the following syntax

```
module.exports = {isEmpty, isNumber}
```

However this throws an error `TypeError: isEmpty is not a function` But when I write the following it works fine

```
module.exports = isEmpty
```

How to correctly export and import multiple functions then?

Following is the utils file

```
const isEmpty = value =>
   value === undefined ||
   value === null ||
   (typeof value === 'object' && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
   (typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length === 0);

const isNumber = () => 
    console.log('hello number')

module.exports = {isEmpty , isNumber}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export multiple functions in this way

`module.exports = { isEmpty , isNumber }`

You basically export an object with `isEmpty` and `isNumber` properties.

Make sure that in the consumer module, `utils` module is imported as an object

```
const utils = require('./utils')
utils.isEmpty([])
```